# Interpreter says bad syntax, but I'm not being able to find the mistake

Tags: python

```
print 'Welcome to the Pig Latin Translator!'

# Start coding here!
original = raw_input("Enter a word:")
if len(original) > 0 :
  print raw_input

  else:
    print "empty"
```

This is what interpreter says:

```
File "python", line 8
    else:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `else` needs to be indented in accordance with your `if`.

Comment: Check your indentation for `else`.

Comment: For clarity: indentation of `if` must match indentation of `else`

Answer (score 4):

Your indentation for your *else* has to follow your *if*.

This is for Python in general, indentation matters.

```
print 'Welcome to the Pig Latin Translator!'

# Start coding here!

original = raw_input("Enter a word:")

if len(original) > 0:
    print raw_input

else:
    print "empty"
```

Comment: so, 4 spaces to each one, nothing else right?

Comment: 4 spaces is good, but make sure its consistent per block

Comment: Each line from a block must have four spaces? or just else, and if?

Comment: Only indent what is in your `if` statement, and what is in your `else` statement. The actual lines with `if` and `else` don't need to be indented. I'll update my answer with code